# Reusing The dbcontext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have seperated my business logic classes from the controllers so that controllers contain as little business logic as possible. But since I want to use the same dbcontext througout the life-time of the web request, and be able to pass the entites with their context live, I am passing on the dbcontext to the business logic classes and almost every method in those classes accept dbcontext as a parameter. (When context is different, I have to query the database to generate the same entity.)

Is there anything wrong with this approach? (Both in terms of trying to use the same context and accepting it as a parameter in each of the business logic methods?)

Comment: It`s probably better to have Data Access Layer - that handle all DB specific  logic, Business Logic should not know DB specific details, like context e.t.c. And context lifetime is better to controll via IoC containers - as a Singleton or One request - one context instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement repository and unit of work design pattern in your project.

> The repository and unit of work patterns are intended to create an abstraction layer between the data access layer and the business logic layer of an application

You've all ready done the separation of business logic layer and data access layer. Now you've to use unit of work pattern for sharing the dbcontext.

> The unit of work class coordinates the work of multiple repositories by creating a single database context class shared by all of them

Read more about the implementation [here](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).